# How does Windows decide which video card should it use for the specific application

Tags: windows, video, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu

How does Windows decide which video card should it use for the specific application?

At first, I thought about NVIDIA Control Panel (and the similar one for the AMD video cards) but it seems that the "Graphics card to use" option is available for the mobile devices such as laptops only.

The next thought was that the system uses the same (preferred) video card for all the applications but apparently it doesn't -- I've checked the "GPU Activity" (that can be enabled by clicking "Desktop" -> "Display GPU Activity Icon in Notification Area" in NVIDIA Control Panel) and there are several apps missing that are currently running on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Every application does not need graphic memory. Windows decide on the basic of blocks of memory free to use and the size of the memory which is required by the application. These memory blocks may be considered separately or combined depending upon the system architecture, graphic memory types etc.